Wikipedia API parse content text template does not exist
I'm using the Wikipedia API to parse the wikitext template (Wikipedia API: Parsing wikitext), but there's something I really don't understand and I can't seem to find the answer.
For example for this Template:Birth date and age {{Birth date and age|1993|2|24}}, I'm using this query (API sandbox):
https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&text=%7B%7BBirth%20date%20and%20age%7C1993%7C2%7C24%7D%7D&prop=text%7Cparsewarnings&contentmodel=wikitext&formatversion=2
but I get as result: Template:Birth date and age (page does not exist)

That error would be correct: No such template exists on mediawiki.org. Perhaps you meant to use the same query on the English Wikipedia instead?
